# When loading a CSV via the UI, is it possible to use the filename to obtain the timestamp?

Tags: splunk

For context: I'm in the process of learning Splunk. I have it running via Docker. I built a PowerShell process that grabs some custom stats from SQL Server every hour and dumps it into a CSV file.

Each CSV file has over 1M records. To save space, I put the timestamp in the filename, rather than having a million entries with the same timestamp over and over.

I'm now trying to load these CSV files into Splunk for analysis...however, it seems it's not possible to use the filename to extract the timestamp.

I have tried searching online, and all solutions I do find are at least a few years old and involve creating various config files.

Is there any sort of naming convention I can use for csv files to help splunk detect the timestamp in the filename? I imagine it's pretty common to have situations where the filename has a date, and then each record only has a time value. In my case, records contain no date/time info. Or maybe some feature I'm missing that lets you parse the timestamp out of the filename?

If I absolutely have to use these config files, that's fine, I think I can change my container to map the $SPLUNK_HOME folder to make it accessible. I was just hoping there was an easier way.

Comment: Be aware that Splunk will struggle with 1M+ events with the exact same timestamp.  You may see messages like "events may not be in the original order".  Try to include at least the time of day for the events.

Comment: @RichG yeah...I've already hit that snag. It seems if you have 100k events with the exact same timestamp, it throws errors. So I'm looking into including the true timestamp when the database itself is scanned. That should hopefully keep it under 100k records per second. Unfortunately, that adds 50% to my file size. But oh well.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but per [docs.Splunk](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Data/Configuretimestamprecognition#Timestamp_settings):

> Set `DATETIME_CONFIG = NONE` to prevent the timestamp processor from running. When timestamp processing is off, Splunk Enterprise does not look at the text of the event for the timestamp and instead uses the event time of receipt, the time the event arrives through its input. For file-based inputs, the event timestamp is taken from from the modification time of the input file.

> Set `DATETIME_CONFIG = CURRENT` to assign the current system time to each event as Splunk Enterprise indexes it.

Comment: I tried this originally but for some reason it's using the upload datetime even though it says it's defaulting to the file moddate. My guess is because I'm using the UI upload, that it's recreating the file temporarily locally and then using that moddate? However, maybe I can map a directory to the container and upload the files "locally" to the splunk service...Worst case scenario, I'll just fix the files and append a timestamp column....only 100m records 

Comment: @ChadBaldwin - it *may* also be worth looking into [dbx](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/2686) to pull data directly instead of the csv intermediary

Comment: @ChadBaldwin - 100m records every hour *seems* awful high ... but maybe it isn't :)

Comment: It sounds like a lot, but it's not. I'm collecting identity column info...~3000 tables with identity columns across 400 databases, so 1.2M records. My background is SQL Server so if I were loading it in there, I would prune the data over time, and also remove unchanging data so that I'm only keeping deltas. But I haven't gotten there yet. I started with CSV because I wanted to collect the data, but wasn't really sure where I was going to put it...still not sure yet, but splunk is an option. And I'll check out dbx, thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry, it's not 100m records every hour...that's total number of records across all files. I have 100+ files, each with 1.2M records.

Comment: @ChadBaldwin - definitely sounds like you should be looking at dbx, then: I *suspect* there is a better way to accomplish what you're trying to do, too - how likely is it that those records are actually changing every hour?